# Business study for career progression

Tags: career-development, software-development, business

I am currently working as a software developer, but looking forward in my career I would like to eventually move into senior roles like Head/CTO

My question is, is it worth studying business at a university (postgraduate certificate/diploma) so that I have an official qualification, or would simply doing online study (Udemy, Coursea etc) be enough to give me the knowledge (but without the quals)?

Comment: not really a qualified answer, but imo, business management is a field that is much more real-world than academic, so generally speaking, I think it's better and more important to improve business management skills through actual managing and being in businesses than to pursue a degree in it. For fields like biochem, research physics, it's absolutely no question to go the academic route. A degree or university degree for business is a good choice insofar as it gets you a management position and fast tracks you toward your goal, but not so much of the education you get per se through the degree

Comment: Too wide a question.  What size and field of business do you want to lead?  MBAs matter more in some of them than others.  The easiest way to get the CTO title is to cofound a startup.  Boom, done.  What do you actually want to be leading?

Comment: Those types of roles are characterised by traits such as leadership, empathy, and interpersonal communication.   In other words, skills which are all about people and therefore are best learnt by getting into other leadership positions.     Software engineers who reach a certain level of experience often find themselves naturally pulled toward leadership and managerial positions due to the fact that employers hire so many junior and inexperienced engineers that any senior developer with decent interpersonal skills generally ends up becoming a "defacto" team leader, mentor or manager.

Comment: This question cannot be answered here because there are so many different paths into those roles and different countries have different expectations. This question also depends on your character and expectations.